# Compilation error only when method is called?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++ but I came across something I found really odd. I have the following method:

```
template <class K, class V>
bool BTree<K,V>::is_in_current_root(BTreeNode* subroot, const K& key){
    if(!subroot){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < subroot->elements.size(); i++){
        if(subroot->elements[i] == key)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I never invoke this method, it compiles just fine. However, as soon as I wrote the invocation like this:

```
if(!is_in_current_root(subroot,pair.key))
   //do something
```

I get the message:

```
fatal error: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long')
      [-Wsign-compare]
    for(int i = 0; i < subroot->elements.size(); i++){
```

Which I know is an issue (I didn't realize the type mismatch at first and it didn't show up as an issue until I specifically called the method). So why did the code compile just fine before calling the `isInCurrentRoot` method? What's happening that differs between when I compile it and invoke the method and when I compile it and don't invoke the method? I thought they should yield the same results, despite their runtime differing.

Comment: The template isn't expanded beyond simple syntax checks until it is actually used. You don't use it = it doesn't exist.

Comment: @WhozCraig that makes a lot of sense, thanks! Is there set rules for what syntax is checked and what isn't? I just find it odd that it will check for some syntax errors and not others (for example, if I add a line of gibberish and never invoke the method, it will still catch it).

Comment: It depends on what settings your compiler's running in regard to warning messages. I don't get this caution on my compiler.

Comment: @Zebrafish my flags are `-std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -g -O0 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -Wfatal-errors -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -MMD -MP -msse2 -c`.

Comment: Maybe it's the -Wfatal-errors. You'll most likely not want to remove the warnings, but cast the int to ::size_type. These warnings are generally a good thing.

Comment: If you have a copy of the standard (mine only covers through 14, so ymmv), see § 14.7 [temp.inst]. You'll probably find most of what you're looking for there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is correct as far as the parser is concerned, when it doesn't consider types of your template arguments.

Your declaration is *syntactically* correct, but the usage is not *semantically* correct.

The first is a requirement for successful compilation in all cases. The second can only be determined if the template is actually used.

If you were to replace your template definition with a non-templated version, substituting `int` for `K` and `size_t` for `V', you'd get the same compilation error, even if the function isn't called.

Templates are basically preprocessor macros on crack. They're not completely evaluated unless they're used, and calling (or instantiating, in the case of a templated class) them with different argument types may generate completely different errors.

Use with caution. You can happily slice bread with a lightsaber, but sometimes a katana is a better choice.